# How to add labels and indicate significant correlations in the chord plot?

Tags: r, correlation, chord-diagram

I have corr_mat where I have stored the correlation between microbiota and metabolite data.
In pmat, I have stored the pvalues from the correlations. I have used the following R plot to create the chord diagram. But I am not sure how to

- firstly filter out and store the significant correlations from pmat
- indicate the significant positive and negative correlations in blue and red color in the chord diagram
- add the labels in the chord diagram

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39PpN.png)

```
library(ggcorrplot)

ggcorrplot(corr_mat)

chordDiagram(
x = corr_mat,
annotationTrack = "grid",
preAllocateTracks = 1)
```

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow, stack! To enable others to help with your code, please consider the general ["how to ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the issue.